# css floating beside fixed element

Tags: css

I need some help with CSS.

I want to create this structure:

I want to create a menu, center-fixed, with 960px; - that's quite simple..

On the same row as the menu, I want to create two div's: one from the left border of the monitor until the nearest of the centered-div from the midle, and another from the next of the centered until the right border of the monitor.

I will try to describe you using keys.

|**left_div**| |**_fixed_centered_960px_div| |__right_div**|

The right and left divs will be fluid and will depends by the screen resolution.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css like this

```
#fixed{
    margin:0 px auto;
    width: 960px;
}    
#container {
    padding-left: 205px;      /* LC fullwidth */
    padding-right: 205px;     /* RC fullwidth + CC padding */
    background:#FFFF99;
}

 #container .column {
    position: relative;
        float: left;
    }

    #center {
        padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;       /* CC padding */
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;
    }
    #content{padding:10px;height:auto;border-right:1px dashed;color:#fed88e;}

    #right{
        width: 205px;             /* RC width */
        padding: 0px;          /* RC padding */
        margin-right: -100%;
    }
#left{
 width : 205px;
padding: 0px
margin-left:-100%;

}
```

and the html like

```
<div id="fixed">
<div id="container">
<div id="center" class="column"></div>
<div id="left" class="column"></div>
<div id="right" class="column"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: definitely doesnt work. This is like

|-------center------|
|--left--||--right--|

Answer (score 1):

Some failed ideas: http://jsfiddle.net/kC35U/ , http://jsfiddle.net/kC35U/1/

The final solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/kC35U/4/

HTML with extra markup:

```
<div id="bar">
  <div class="left"><div>LEFT</div></div>
  <div class="right"><div>RIGHT</div></div>
  <div class="center">CENTER</div>
</div>
<div>
  Footer
</div>​
```

CSS:

Center div, fixed width, centered, nothing special:

```
.center {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now, make two 50% wide wrapper divs for the left/right sides. Set their height to 0 to keep all three div's top aligned nicely:

```
.left {
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 0;
}

.right {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 0;
}
```

Internal divs fill their parent, but we cut off the half width of the center div.

```
.left > div {
    margin-right: 250px;
}

.right > div {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

If you want to put something below the three columns, then you have to use some weird tricks:

```
.left:after, .right:after {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  height: 0;
}

#bar + * {
    clear: both;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can get what you want using this:

[The Holy Grail 3 column liquid layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm)

Just add:

`#col1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;
}`

You may need additional tinkerage.

Comment: this is not what the OP asked. The OP wants a fixed centered div and on the sides the div sizes should be auto. This is exactly the opposite(Fixed side divs and auto center div).